# Fail a grunt build when debug prints exist in source

Tags: gruntjs, build-process, post-processing, software-quality, debug-print

I am working on a PHP/Javascript project where I've nicely set up a build workflow. It involves testing, minifying, compressing into the final zip deliverable, and a whole lot of other nice stuff.

**I want to build a task that fails when there are certain patterns in the source code.** I would like to look for any `print_r()`, `error_log()`, `var_dump()`, etc functions, and halt the build process if there are any. Perhaps later I would like to check for things in Javascript or CSS so this is not only a PHP question.

I know it can be done with `grunt-shell` and `grep` but I'd like to know the following:

1. **Are there any grunt plugins specific to this task?** Ideally I would like to be able to specify a list of regexes per file type, and to set whether to continue or fail the build on pattern match.
2. **How do others tackle the problem** of double-checking the packaged source for the most common debug statements or other patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer to my question, but I've recently come across this grunt plugin which is somewhat related. It removes `console.log` statements from JavaScript. Haven't tried it yet. Looks good. I still would like to know if there's something similar for PHP though.

http://grunt-tasks.com/grunt-remove-logging-calls/

**Edit:** Seeing as there's only tumbleweeds rolling in the wind here, I'm posting my workaround that's based on `grunt-shell`. However this is not what I was looking for. It's not perfect because it doesn't do proper syntax parsing:

```
    shell: {
        check_debug_prints: {
            command: '(! (egrep -r "var_dump|print_r|error_log" --include=*.php src || egrep -r "console\.\w+|debugger;" --include=*.js src) ) || (echo "Debug prints in source - build aborted" && false )'
        }
    },
```

and

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-shell' );
```

**Edit 2:** I finally found the exact grunt plugin I was looking for. It is [grunt-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-search). There is a `failOnMatch` boolean option that lets you indicate if a particular regex pattern should cause the build to fail when found.